# How to fix jquery mobile 1.3.0 preventing changepage method when combined with Knockout click bind

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Since i updated jquery mobile to the newest version, 1.3.0 my links in listviews don't work anymore. I figured out that the problem is knockoutJS after trying it without this line.

```
data-bind="click: viewmodel.function"
```

I use a hack to fix it now, i add this line to the a element:

```
onclick="$.mobile.changePage('#mypage')"
```

I opened an issue on the jquery mobile github page too but i wanted to know if anyone else has been having problems with this. I made an example of this problem on http://jsbin.com/ijoyeb/6/edit

Comment: Issue on github.com https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5796#issuecomment-15233354

Comment: Your jsbin is working strange for me... however you can try to return `true` from your KO click handler: `this.test = function() {
        //do nothing
        return true;
      }`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ijoyeb/9/edit

Done that but doesn't change much, though when i keep clicking now the page eventually changes